# Why doesn't alert manager include query in the link?

Tags: prometheus, go-templates, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an alert manager deployment that has a similar config as [this](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/main/template/default.tmpl#L2). I receive the alert in a slack channel and when I click that it gets me this page `${ExternalURL}/#/alerts?receiver=slack` but as you can understand from the link, it doesn't include the query hence it can't show me related results. How can I fix this and have the query in the link in order to show results in Prometheus?

```
{{ define "__alertmanagerURL" }}{{ .ExternalURL }}/#/alerts?receiver={{ .Receiver | urlquery }}{{ end }}
```

Comment: I believe there is some kind of confusion here. My understanding is that `urlquery` encodes `.Receiver` to be query parameter. To get URL leading to alert itself, I believe you need to used something like `{{ (index .Alerts 0).GeneratorURL }}`. Seen [here](https://hodovi.cc/blog/creating-awesome-alertmanager-templates-for-slack/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/milesbxf/e2744fc90e9c41b47aa47925f8ff6512)